# Looking for a particular font from an old logo

Tags: font-identification

I've been tasked with recreating the logo from and old ID badge. There are some texts on the logo and one baffles me in particular. Unfortunately the client doesn't have the original project file.

WhatTheFont can't scan it properly for me and returns bad results, Photoshop Font Match doesn't do the trick either, and I can't seem to find it in my Font Vault, Google Fonts or TypeKit.

Maybe I've just overlooked it, but I've been looking for hours now and can't seem to find anything.

[image: wisła with color]
[image: wisła without color]

Note that the fourth character is [polish ł](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Monotype Corsiva, spacing can be manually tuned, no way to input the polish letter to be sure

(edited the polish letter to l and adjusted all colors to the same grey to get a regonizable image for the common font identifying machines. No use to try to cut out of the background the low resolution shape.)

[image]

Comment: I just did some color masking and thought that will do the trick. I've been obviously wrong. Thanks!